# Getting "Use of moved value" in a loop

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm making Tic-tac-toe in Rust. I want to count the amount of cells in a line, when the player is moving. Like -- x --. So I call count_result two times with the same `dx` and `dy` (that's why I pass `dx` and `dy` by reference). But here's the problem. My linter in IntelliJ IDEA complains that I use moved value. The compiler compiles without any warnings. What is the problem? Can you help me?

[IntelliJ IDEA screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/307bj.png)

Just to clarify - `game_data.board` is `[[Option<Cell>; 3]; 3]`

```rust
struct Data {
    board: [[Option<Cell>; 3]; 3],
}
```

```rust
fn count_result(game_data: &Data, point: &Point, cell: &Cell, dx: &isize, dy: &isize) -> isize {
    let mut count: isize = 0;
    let point = (*point).clone();
    let mut x = point.x;
    let mut y = point.y;
    while (x + dx < 3 && x + dx >= 0) && (y + dy >= 0 && y + dy < 3) {
        x += 1;
        y += 1;
        if game_data.board[x as usize][y as usize] == Some(*cell) {
             count += 1;
        } else {
             break;
        }
    }
    count
}
```

Here is another example of the same problem.
`game_data: &mut Data`

[IntelliJ IDEA screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS1c7.png)

Comment: Looks like an IDE bug.

Comment: Try clear the caches.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a linter indexing invalid state. Just invalidate caches and you'll be fine.